# How do I reset database access privileges to initial state?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I noticed it on our PostgreSQL server (v12.7). There are two similar DBs with weirdly different access permissions:

```
postgres=> \l+
                                                                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges          |   Size    | Tablespace |                Description                 
-----------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 postgres  | skadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                                     | 8257 kB   | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 alpha     | skadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                                     | No Access | pg_default | 
 betta     | skadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                                     | 5806 MB   | pg_default |
```

Note that `skadmin` is the owner for all of the DBs but has **no access** to `alpha` only.
Of course this user is able to grant any access to any of these DBs:

```
postgres=> grant CONNECT on DATABASE alpha TO skadmin;
```

But it makes the privileges looking like

```
   Name    |  Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges          |   Size    | Tablespace |                Description                 
-----------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 postgres  | skadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                                     | 8257 kB   | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 alpha     | skadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | skadmin=c/skadmin                   | 6971 MB   | pg_default | 
 betta     | skadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                                     | 5806 MB   | pg_default |
```

If I revoke the `CONNECT` privilege (or `ALL`) on that DB from `skadmin` then it won't be able to connect to there anymore (even though it is the owner).

So I'm wondering – what does make these two DBs behaving so differently? How come is it possible to connect to `betta` without explicit privileges set whereas not possible to connect to `alpha` without explicit privileges? These two DBs – `alpha` and `betta` are supposed to be identical in their schemas and access rights after all. Eventually I'd prefer not to have any explicit privileges granted to the owner at all.